# Grouping radio buttons in c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I Have a form in which I display a menu. Each menu has a section and choices as below:

```
Starters

Prawn Cocktail 
Soup

Mains

Beef
Lamb
```

I am looping through the menu sections and menu choices for that section, for each menu option I want a radio button and to group them together per section so that only one menu option can be selected per section. By default the top selection will be selected. This is what I have so far

In the model

```
public List<MenuCourses> courses {get; set;}
public List<MenuOptions> options {get;set;}
```

and in the view

```
@for ( int i = 0; i < Model.MenuCourses.Count(); i++ ){

      @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.MenuCourses[i].CourseTitle )

      // loop options
      for ( int k = 0; k < Model.MenuOptions.Count(); k++ ){

          if(Model.MenuOptions[k].MenuCoursesID == Model.MenuCourses[i].MenuCoursesID){

             @Html.DisplayFor(m=> m.MenuOptions[k].Title)
             //NEED RADIO BUTTON HERE BUT HOW DO I BIND TO THE MODEL?

           }
       }
```

I need each menu option to have a radio button grouped to that section, and when the user hits save I need to pick up which menu options has been selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understand well, you need dynamic radio button lists. In that case try following the instructions on [this blog](http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/). It solves the problem using the `EditorTemplates` feature. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with **EditorTemplates**.

Let's create 3 view models for our scenario.

```
public class Course
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name{ set; get; }
    public List<Option> Options{ set; get; }
    public int SelectedAnswer { set; get; }
    public Course()
    {
        Options= new List<Option>();
    }
}
public class Option
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Title { set; get; }
}
public class OrderViewModel 
{
    public List<Course> Courses{ set; get; }
    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        Courses= new List<Course>();
    }
}
```

In our `GET` action method for the view, we will create an object of our OrderViewModel class and set the Course collection and it’s Options properties and then send that to the view by passing it to the View method.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm= new OrderViewModel();

    //the below is hard coded for DEMO. you may get the data from some  
    //other place and set the course and options

    var q1 = new Course { ID = 1, Name= "Starters" };
    q1.Options.Add(new Option{ ID = 12, Title = "Prawn Cocktail " });
    q1.Options.Add(new Option{ ID = 13, Title = "Soup" });
    vm.Courses.Add(q1);     

    var q2 = new Course { ID = 1, Name= "Mains" };
    q2.Options.Add(new Option{ ID = 42, Title = "Beef" });
    q2.Options.Add(new Option{ ID = 43, Title = "Lamp" });
    vm.Courses.Add(q2);

   return View(vm);           
}
```

Now go to the `~/Views/YourControllerName` folder and create a folder called `EditorTemplates`. Create a new view there with the name `Course.cshtml`. Add the below code to that file

```
@model Course
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.ID)
    <h3> @Model.Name</h3>
    @foreach (var a in Model.Options)
    {
       <p>
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(b=>b.SelectedAnswer,a.ID)  @a.Title
       </p>
    }
</div>
```

Now go to the main view and use `EditorFor` html helper method to bring the editortemplate

```
@model OrderViewModel 
<h2>Your Order</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Courses)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

To get the selected items on  form submit, you can do this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(OrderViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var q in model.Courses)
        {
            var qId = q.ID;
            var selectedAnswer = q.SelectedAnswer;
            // Save the data 
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ThankYou"); //PRG Pattern
    }
    //to do : reload courses and options on model.
    return View(model);
}
```

This is clearly explained in [this blog post](http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/) with a working sample which you can download and run yourself and see how it works.

Comment: Excellent, I did see the downloadable code but my own implementation of it did not work however following this did. Thanks for the further detail relating to my project

Comment: You are welcome. Glad i could help. infact i am the one who wrote that post. :)

Comment: I have a new question on this topic here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085485/loading-selected-radio-buttons-using-an-editor-c-sharp

Comment: @CR41G14: I wrote an answer for that.

Comment: I know that this answer is old, but if the author @Shyju is still monitoring changes on this page, I do have a quick question. Is the generation of the 'sub' view page absolutely necessary or does it really facilitate ease on page development? I will be experimenting but I was wondering based on your greater experience in this area.